AWS ec2 instance:I used dynamic public ip address. after that i used static ip but my project is not run at new ip address. how to fix this issue?
I created aws ec2 instance using ubuntu machine with nginx server for wordpress website and I used dynamic public ip address. Now i used static ip but my project is not run at new ip address. how to fix this issue?
my website is already created on wordpress. but when i change my ip so my website is not running. I want to run my wordpress site with my static ip address. (No domain)
expected url: http://65.1.84.172/ (run my wordpress website this type of static url)

Connect via ssh to the instance and edit the file wp-config.php (it is in the root of Wordpress installation).
Edit these two lines:
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );


Navigate to “Settings” > “General” in the admin area.
There you will find the input fields where you can change the WordPress site URL or the website URL.
Here you have to write your static ip http://65.1.84.172/
After that change your ec2 instance ip.

I can't open wordpress dashboard because my wordpress is running on aws ec2 IP address. now i change my ip then url is not working with another ip address.
I also restart my nginx server. but i didn't work.
